# Add windy.js on leaflet map as a layer

Tags: php, html, leaflet

i want to add wind data on my leaflet map as a layer 
wind data like this https://danwild.github.io/leaflet-velocity/

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#data-providers

Answer (score 0):

> I've been working on something similar. I found a pretty good looking
>   and intuitive method being used to represent vector information. Have
>   a look at the following examples:
>
> http://earth.nullschool.net/
>
> http://hint.fm/wind/
>
> http://air.nullschool.net/
>
> http://googlemapsmania.blogspot.com/2014/07/the-growth-of-slippy-wind-map.html
>
> In my case, I still need to find a suitable format for the wind/ocean
>   data I want to plot on my Leaflet map. It's certainly not a quick fix,
>   but man, it looks great!
>
> Maybe this can help you too. I hope to be able to post a working
>   solution soon.
>
> This plugin takes input data in form of speed in knots (nautical miles
>   (1.852 km) per hour) and direction in degrees. It then generates the
>   wind barbs and outputs an icon. This icon can easily be added to a
>   Leaflet marker.
>
> You can download it here:
>   https://github.com/JoranBeaufort/Leaflet.windbarb And you can see a
>   live example here: http://www.geonet.ch/leaflet-windbarb/